# Limits and Identities

Tags: limits

The sum $S_N$ is defined by $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N n^5$. Using the identity

$(n +1/2 )^6 -(n-1/2)^6 = 6n^5 +5n^3 +8n$,
find $S_N$ in terms of $N$. [You need not simplify your result.]
Hence find $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}N^{-λ}S_N$ for each of the two cases:

(i) $λ = 6$,

(ii) $λ > 6$.

I have the answer but not sure how they got it.

Comment: The equality you gave was wrong it should say $\frac{3}{8}n$ instead of $8n$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem wants you to use more well known formulas to come up with less well known formulas, in that case we have,

$$\left((n +\frac{1}{2} )^6 -(n-\frac{1}{2})^6\right)-5n^3-\frac{3}{8}n = 6n^5$$

Taking the sum from $n=1$ to $N$ on both sides.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left((n +\frac{1}{2} )^6 -(n-\frac{1}{2})^6\right)-5 \sum_{n=1}^{N} n^3-\frac{3}{8} \sum_{n=1}^{N} n=6 \sum_{n=1}^{N} n^5$$

The first sum is telescoping, the others we will use formulas to get.

$$(N+\frac{1}{2})^6-(\frac{1}{2})^6-5\left(\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\right)^2-\frac{3}{8}\left(\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\right)=6S_N$$

Form which you solve for $S_N$.

For the limit it is clear that $S_N=\frac{N^6}{6}+....$. So that the limit of $N^{-6}S_N=\frac{1}{6}+\text{terms, of, negative, exponents}$ as $n \to \infty$ goes to $\frac{1}{6}$.

For $\lambda>6$ the quantity $N^{-\lambda}S_N$ must haves all terms negative exponents, and thus $\lim_{N \to \infty} N^{-\lambda}S_n=0$,